# How to pass arguments to a function in for loop Jinja DJANGo

Tags: django, jinja2

How can I pass an argument to a function in for loop?
I use Django and jinja and I want to somehow pass an argument to my function but I don't know whether it is possible, didn't find any pieces of information online

```
{% for student in get_students%}
                <tr>
                    <td>User.name</td>
                    {% for colum in get_columns %}
                    {% for grade in colum.get_grade_by_user(student.id) %} <=== like that
                    <td>{{grade.value}}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}

def get_grade_by_user(self, student):
       get_grade = Grade.objects.all().filter(date=self.id, user=student)
       return get_grade
```

Comment: I think it is no. did you try to  put the method into ```@property``` and call it like colum.get_grade_by_user?

Comment: @ha-neul I can, but I have to pass an argument somehow

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the global namespace by adding a reference to your functions before loading the templates:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

def my_funct(a, b):
    return a + b

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('/path/to/templates'))
env.globals['my_funct'] = my_funct
```